(New) link for Google Tasks redirects to calendar view when creating a Chrome shortcut
When I create a new Chrome shortcut for https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r/tasks, Google redirects to calendar view. The link works as a regular bookmark though. Can I create a Chrome shortcut that opens task view by default?

You have two different questions here. Please ask only a single question per post. Edit your post to pick just one. Assuming you'll be asking the first question: Are you able to create just a link or shortcut on your Desktop to Tasks that works, taking you to the correct Tasks page/view?

OK, got it. Done.

Have you tried creating a regular shortcut (not a Chrome/app shortcut) and does that go to the right place? Please read my entire comment and put the information you learn or have to add in your question.

OK, better now?
